# Form Not Populating New SharePoint Field

Tags: form

We have a form that populates a SharePoint list. We added an additional DateTime field to the list and then to the form. Submitting a filled-in form does not populate the newly added field in the SharePoint list. The names match. Is there a non-intuitive step we need to take?

Comment: is it an infopath form or a custom webpart or a dataform created in designer?

Comment: Make sure that the current view of your list does not have a specific filter that not matched with your new entry .